# Copy data from one row in Dataframe A to a specific row in Dataframe B in python/pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've been struggling with this assignment quite long now and I cant seem to get the correct solution. My problem is as follows: I have imported two worksheets (A & B) from an Excelfile and assigned these to two Dataframe variables. Worksheets A & B have rows with similar names however the cells in Worksheet B are empty whereas the cells in Worksheet A contain numbers. My assignment is to copy the rows from worksheet A to worksheet B. This needs to be done in a specific order. For example: in worksheet A the row sales revenue is at index 1, but in worksheet B the row sales revenue is at index 5. Does anybody know how to do this? Im an absolute beginner with python/pandas. [I have included a printscreen of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXSaI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to merge the two tables using left join

```
#remove all Nan columns 
df_data3 = df_data3[['Unnamed:0']]
df_data3 = pd.merge(df_data3,df_data2,on='Unnamed:0',how='left')
```

see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html for more option play with it a bit to better understand how this work

it is similar to SQL join

Comment: Hi Gal, Thanks for wanting to help me out. However, when I use your solution I get the following error code: KeyError: "None of [Index(['Unname:0'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: this is proboly as I made some mistake in the command column name I think it need to be Unnamed: 0 use you have the code use the correct name

Comment: Hi gal, sadly it still didnt work I still get all NaN in my lower table...